# Datagrip simple calculation on the Select Query Result

Tags: amazon-redshift, datagrip, aginity

I recently switch from Aginity for Redshift to Datagrip for accessing my redshift db. I am wondering for Datagrip is it a function to get simple calculations (like count, sum) on certain columns of the select results like the Aginity for Redshift? It is very handy function when doing a quick check for the result return.  Appreciate for your help all.

Comment: I also use Datagrip with Redshift, There are no data profiling features.

Comment: Please, follow: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-5278

Comment: I don't like Datagrip, because datagrip has a big limitation. Aginity Pro has limitations too but right now for me number one is Aginity Pro